# Why was US-made Reaper drone downed but not Byraktar TB2?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Russian Su-27s used fuel dumping techniques on US-made MQ-9 Reaper ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/LqsSYp-51Hs)) and Turkish Byraktar TB2 ([YouTube](https://youtu.be/Zfjye44RKo8)).

MQ-9 Reaper plunged into the Black Sea, but TB2 didn't.

Why was that?

Answer (score 8):

Because the Russian aircraft had a mid air collision with the MQ9 drone and not the Turkish one.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @user366312 - That is exactly what happened. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: The video shows no collision.

Comment: The propeller blade didn't bend itself. The answers in this topic outline why you do not see the instant of impact. https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/98162/why-is-there-no-video-of-the-drone-propellor-strike-by-russia

Answer (score 0):

The general feeling of analysts is that despite the Russians' bravado on the subject, there is other stuff going on behind the curtain.  First, Russian aviation knows that the unintended collision with the Reaper was an embarrassment to the service, and doesn't care to repeat it, so they are being more cautious. Second, analysts are right - you never know what can happen in a collision like that, you can just as easily "own goal" and kill your own plane too.  They were also mindful of the geopolitical implications, so were probably trying to turn it down a notch.

Anyway, it is the view of the analysts I read that in the course of the intercept, they never looked at the insignia.  Otherwise they would've just splashed it with guns.